# Конструктор надо сделать

Tags: c++

Не могу понять одну фишку есть вот такой рабочий код

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
class Set  // класс множество
{              // Открытие класса
private:   // Приватные поля
unsigned int size_massiv;  // размер массива
unsigned int* array;  // указатель массива
public:   // Публичные
Set() { size_massiv=0; array = new unsigned int[size_massiv]; } // 
конструктор
Set(int k) {  size_massiv = k; array = new unsigned int[size_massiv]; // 
конструктор с аргументами для выделения памяти
for ( unsigned i = 0; i < size_massiv; i++)  // цикл для конструктора
array[i] = 0;  }
void Enter(); // метод для ввода
void Show(); // метод для вывода
void Obed(Set, Set); // метод объединение
void Perecech(Set, Set); // метод пресечения
unsigned int& operator [] (int i);  // оператор [](с помощью перегрузки)
void Raznost(Set, Set); // метод разность
bool bez_povt(const unsigned int&);  // метод для уникальности элементов
};   // Закрытие класса
void Set::Enter() // метод для ввода
{
cout << "Введите размер множества " << endl;  // Приглашения для ввода 
размера множества
cin >> size_massiv;  // ввод размера множества
array = new unsigned int[size_massiv];
unsigned int buf; // переменная для уникальных элементов 
for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < size_massiv; i++)  // цикл для ввода элементов 
множества
{
cout << "Введите элемент " << i + 1 << ")   "; // Приглашения для ввода 
элементов множества
cin >> buf ; // Ввод элементов множества
if(bez_povt(buf)) // Условие для логической функции bez_povt со значением 
buf
        array[i] = buf; // Приравнивание array к buf
    else
    {
        cout << "Element \'" << buf << "\' already exist!" << endl;  //вывод 
  сообщения что это элемент уже есть.
        i--;
}
}
}
void Set::Show()  // Метод для отображения множества
{
cout << "Множество " << endl; // Надпись "Множество"
 for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < size_massiv; i++)  // Цикл для вывода 
множества
cout << array[i] << " "; // Вывод элементов получившегося множества
cout << endl;
}
bool Set::bez_povt(const unsigned int& s) //Метод для уникальности множеств
{
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < size_massiv; i++)  
if(s == array[i]) 
    return false; // возращение лжи
 return true;  // возвращение правды
 }
 void Set::Obed(Set a, Set b) // Объединение двух множеств
 {
 size_massiv = a.size_massiv + b.size_massiv;  // размер множества равен 
  сумме размеров двух множеств
  array = new unsigned int[size_massiv];
  unsigned i, j, count = 0;
  unsigned int n = a.size_massiv; // Приравниваем  n = a.size_massiv
 for ( i = 0; i < a.size_massiv; i++) // Цикл для множества а, начинаем идти 
 с начала массива
 array[i] = a.array[i];  // Приравнивание элементов

 for ( i = 0; i < b.size_massiv; i++)  // Цикл для множества b
 {
 for ( j = 0; j < a.size_massiv; j++)  // Цикл для множества a
 if(b.array[i] == a.array[j])  // условие равенства двух элементов двух 
  множеств a и b
  continue;  // продолжение
  else  // условие иначе
  count++;  // Увеличение счётчика count
 if(count == a.size_massiv)  // Условие равенства
  array[n++] = b.array[i];
  count = 0; // счетчик count =0
   }
  size_massiv = n; // Размер массива = n
  }
  void Set::Perecech(Set a, Set b)  // Пересечение двух множеств
 {
 size_massiv = a.size_massiv + b.size_massiv;  // размер множества равен 
 сумме размеров двух множеств
 array = new unsigned int[size_massiv];
 unsigned int i, j, n = 0;
 for ( i = 0; i < a.size_massiv; i++)  // Цикл для множества a
 for ( j = 0; j < b.size_massiv; j++)  // Цикл для множества b
 {
 if(a.array[i] == b.array[j])  // условие равенства двух элементов двух 
 множеств a и b
 {
  array[n++] = a.array[i];
  continue;
 }
 }
  size_massiv = n;  // Размер массива = n
 }
 void Set::Raznost(Set a, Set b) // разность двух множеств
  {
 array = new unsigned int[size_massiv]; 
  unsigned int i, n = 0; // введение переменных
 for (int i = 0; i < a.size_massiv; i++) // цикл для размера множества а
 { int j = 0;  // Введение переменной
 while (j < b.size_massiv && b.array[j] != a.array[i]) j++;  //пока j меньше 
 размера множества b и элементы двух множеств не равны
  if (j == b.size_massiv)  array[n++] = a.array[i]; // условие если j 
  =размеру множества b 
  }
 size_massiv = n;  // Размер массива = n
 }
 unsigned int& Set::operator[](int i)  // Оператор []
 {
 return array[i];  // Возвращение элементов array
 }
```

Значит нужен мне конструктор, который будет заполнять случайными не повторяющимися числами массив ну и производить над его объектами операции 
Вот код моего заполнения просто случайными повторяющимися числами.

```
   Set(unsigned int r)
   {
   size_massiv = r; array = new unsigned int[size_massiv];
   for ( unsigned i = 0; i < size_massiv; i++) 
   array[i] = rand()%30;
   }
```

Он работает но фишка в том что все элементы множества это нули, помогите разобраться с нулями и заполнить массив уникальными числами

Comment: Сначала грешил на конструкторы поэтому попробывал     так 
           Set() {  } 
           Set(int k) {  size_massiv = k; array = new unsigned 
           int[size_massiv]; 
            }         но проблему это не решилло

Comment: А вы случаем не вызываете перегрузку `Set(int k)`?

Comment: Да нет вроде перегрузки. Да я  и не умею конструкторы перегружать. Это просто конструктор для выделения памяти

Comment: У вас перегруженные конструкторы `Set(int k)` и `Set(unsigned int r)`.

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, вы вызываете что-то вроде

```
Set set(10);
```

Литерал 10 - это число типа `int`. И вы зануляете все элементы. А вот вы вызовите так:

```
Set set(10u);
```

То есть для `unsigned int` - тогда должен вызываться конструктор для `unsigned int`, с рандомным наполнением.

Comment: Спасибо большое это действительно помогло. Возьму на вооружение.

Comment: Здесь спасибо - это голосование за ответ...

Answer (score 0):

Я сделал вот так

```
Set(unsigned int r)
{
 size_massiv = r; array = new unsigned int[size_massiv];
 bool povtor;
 for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < size_massiv;) 
 {
    int newarrray = rand()%30;
    povtor = false;
    for ( unsigned int j = 0; j < i; j++)
   {
    if(array[j]==newarrray)
    {
        povtor = true;
        break;
    }
    }
  if(!povtor)
  {
 array[i]= newarrray;
    i++;
 }

 }

 }
```

Но есть одна загвоздка когда я хочу воспользоваться srand(time(NULL) к у меня элементы обоих массивов одинаковые как исправить?

Comment: `srand` надо вызывать только один раз в программе вообще - где-нибудь в первых строках `main` напишите его и больше не трогайте.